# Как вывести JSONArray на HTML страницу в AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Решил подучить AngularJs. И вот такая проблема

Есть контроллер и  html  страница. В контроллере получаю  JSONARRAy и пытаюсь его вывести на страницу. но ничего не получается. Если ссылку меняю которая ворачивает JSON String  то все выводится. перерыл все и циклами и чем отлько не пробовал

вот сам контроллер

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.view3', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view3', {
            templateUrl: 'view3/view3.html',
            controller: 'View3Ctrl'
        });
    }])

    .controller('View3Ctrl',function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.my_name = "Pasha";
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
        });
    });
```

Вот страница

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My view</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="View3Ctrl">
<p> Hello Pavel</p>
<div>{{my_name}}</div>
<div>{{myWelcome}}</div>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Я пробовал и так

```
<div ng-repeat="f in myWelcome">
    {{f.key}}-{{f.value}}
</div>
```

и так

```
<div ng-repeat="value in faq">
    <div ng-repeat="(question,answer) in myWelcome">
        {{question}} - {{answer}}
    </div>
</div>
```

ничего не выводится

Comment: Если делаешь в планкере или чём-то подобном, обрати внимание на протокол, защищённый или нет. Может просто данные не приходят?

Comment: как связан код контроллера приведенного в вопросе с кодом страницы? на странице не подключаются скрипты, непонятный `</table>`. что за `faq` если в контроллере определена только переменная `myWelcome`? Приведите [минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Да вроде выводится
 [Тут](http://plnkr.co/edit/tLA04UJmtPkO1ttnS4nV?p=preview)

Файл directive.client.view.html

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in directive.items">
  <p>{{item.Type}} - {{item.Region}} - {{item.PostalCode}} - {{item.Lat}} - {{item.Lon}} - {{item.Distance}}</p>
   </div>
```